# The subreport with static text is not showing

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have created a very simple sub report "dummy_subreport.jrxml", which prints a static text.
dummy_subreport.jasper is included in the report "Calling_report.jrxml", which also prints a static text and includes the subreport.

However, the subreport is not getting displayed when the main report is invoked.

Subreport code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="dummy_subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="286" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[From sub report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The calling report is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Calling_report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="133" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="60" y="12" width="410" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[HELLO WORLD IN THE COVERING REPORT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="261" y="58" width="200" height="52"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["dummy_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example working well (the text from subreport was rendered well) in case passing datasource at main report (I used "One Empty Record" dataadapter at JSS, for example). Did you pass datasource to the main report?

Comment: There is no datasource passed (it is set as "One Empty Record")